# EXCEL Prevent range from being deleted

Tags: excel

[image]

I want to be able to delete or add rows in Section A without moving Section B without protecting the sheet.

Is there a way to sort of 'freeze' all those columns so they won't move? so if the user just wants more columns they can just right click on a entire row to add, or delete

Help is appreciated!

Comment: So insert horizontal spans of cells of appropriate length to A, instead of entire rows?

Comment: yes, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, which is why I am suggesting it.

Comment: besides that is there a way to sort of 'freeze' all those columns so they won't move? so if the user just wants more columns they can just right click on a entire row to add, or delete

Comment: Selecting all columns where you want to insert/delete you want (e.g. A9:e17) and then insert with Shift cells down, or delete)?

Comment: Why not to put **B** above **A**?

Answer (score -1):

### Delete

Select exactly what you want to delete. Press `Ctrl` + `-` (Control and Minus Sign) or choose **Delete...** in a context menu. Choose **Shift cells up** in a pop-up menu.

[image]

### Insert

Select the range to insert. Press `Ctrl` + `+` (Control and Plus Sign) or choose **Insert...** in a context menu. Choose **Shift cells Down** in a pop-up menu.

[image]

---

### Answer to additional question

> Is there a way to sort of *freeze* all those columns so they won't
> move when the user wants more rows to add?

In general - no. But if you manage to convert the left side (**A** in your picture) into an [Excel Table aka Excel List](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) then you can [operate with rows and columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resize-a-table-by-adding-or-removing-rows-and-columns-e65ae4bb-e44b-43f4-ad8b-7d68784f1165) inside of it.

Comment: This is an answer suitable for superuser.com. Here, the assumption is that the OP wanted to do this programmatically, otherwise the question should be closed altogether.

Comment: @GSerg IMO the less you code the better. Sometimes, to get what you want, it's enough to reorder the data or redefine the task, rather than trying to program. I'm sure this is exactly the case. Anyway, if it's you who downvoted the answer, I'm glad you left a few words explaining your point.